# Badges : Improvement Suggestion

Tags: discussion, badges

This is just a suggestion I have which I believe would improve the user experience. Currently the Badges tab has , all the badges listed and there is tick mark besides the ones the user has achieved.

e.g

`Pundit` Left 10 comments with score of 5 or more

But a user has no idea as to , how many comments does he currently have which has score of 5 or more. If while hovering over the Badge tag , the user could get the count of current count of his comments which satisfy the requirement of score 5 or more , this would encourage the user improve quality of the comment and provide him something to look forward to .

e.g

When hovering of `Pundit` , it should show 2/10 , which means user needs to get to 10 to achieve this Badge , but currently he has only 2 such comments.

I understand that this is not feasible for all the badges, but this can be implemented in badges it is feasible for.

Comment: I'd be also interested to learn the number of comments I _currently_ have with a score of 5 or more _after_ I already have the badge.

Comment: Well that was my first thought , if that is feasible it would be ideal . Alternatively if site doesn't want to save too much user data , they can just keep and display this data till user reached the Badge requirements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To see your comment score overview and their star number, do the following.

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/947/my-comment-score-distribution

Go to the link above, enter your user id from Stack Overflow.

```
Ex : http://stackoverflow.com/users/392233/misguided
                                    ^^^^^^
```

Enter 392233 and click Run Query. Ta'Da

---

Also, I have almost 700 comments on SO. And I just got the Pundit badge like 5 days ago or so. It can be hard to get it on SO.

I'm pretty sure the reason that they don't have this functionality included in the site itself, is that it causes a lot of drain on the system resources, and thus would negatively impact the speed of the site. Well, I'm sure they could get it to work fast, but it's really just too much work doing all that, for letting every user know how far away they are from getting a silver badge.